# Replace multiple values in string using replace, sub string and find in Python

Tags: python

So im pulling issues from our jira project and I need to replace url's with new formatted url's in the description.
old description contains the old sharepoint server URL's so I need to change them to our new online Sharepoint url.
I decided to use Python to make use of the atlassian plugin.
here is a version of how the description looks like in the jira issue currently:

```
Good day 

we need a new validation on the External Reference when doing work pads or amending manually when we do refund, it seems that the user that updates this is using Tab or Enter and therefore the payment files fails ,

we need users to be validated while updating refund reference same way as we limited claims payments for updating invoice numbers

thank you 
regards 

*BRS & FRS:*
[BRS_FRS_PS_ACC_Payments_v20.0|http://portal.mycompany.local/mycompany/someproject/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/someproject/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fmycompany%2Fsomeproject%2Fsomeproject%2F06%20Solution%20Documentation%2F03%20Accounting%2C%20Etc%2F07%20TIA%2FBRS%20%26%20FRS&View=%7B9A71C976%2D85D3%2D4D34%2D828B%2DE5B1B428EA5E%7D]
[BRS_FRS_PS_ACC_Workpads_Manual_Write_Off_and_Incomming_Paument_v5.0|http://portal.mycompany.local/mycompany/someproject/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/someproject/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fmycompany%2Fsomeproject%2Fsomeproject%2F06%20Solution%20Documentation%2F03%20Accounting%2C%20Etc%2F07%20TIA%2FBRS%20%26%20FRS&View=%7B9A71C976%2D85D3%2D4D34%2D828B%2DE5B1B428EA5E%7D]

*Sign Offs:*
[BRS_FRS_PS_ACC_Payments_v20.0|http://portal.mycompany.local/mycompany/someproject/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/someproject/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fmycompany%2Fsomeproject%2Fsomeproject%2F06%20Solution%20Documentation%2F03%20Accounting%2C%20Etc%2F07%20TIA%2FBRS%20%26%20FRS%2FSign%2Doffs%2FPayments%2FV20%2E0&FolderCTID=0x0120005C60D5FB65C2C84191CB5ACDFD820AA6&View=%7B9A71C976%2D85D3%2D4D34%2D828B%2DE5B1B428EA5E%7D]
[BRS_FRS_PS_ACC_Workpads_Manual_Write_Off_and_Incomming_Paument_v5.0|http://portal.mycompany.local/mycompany/someproject/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/someproject/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fmycompany%2Fsomeproject%2Fsomeproject%2F06%20Solution%20Documentation%2F03%20Accounting%2C%20Etc%2F07%20TIA%2FBRS%20%26%20FRS%2FSign%2Doffs%2FWorkpads%20%26%20incoming%20payments%2FV5%2E0&FolderCTID=0x0120005C60D5FB65C2C84191CB5ACDFD820AA6&View=%7B9A71C976%2D85D3%2D4D34%2D828B%2DE5B1B428EA5E%7D]

*Technical Documentation:*
N/A

*Unit Testing:*
[TU_dd-1821|http://portal.mycompany.local/mycompany/someproject/SitePages/Home.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fmycompany%2Fsomeproject%2Fsomeproject%2F06%20Solution%20Documentation%2F03%20Accounting%2C%20Etc%2F07%20TIA%2FUnit%20Testing&FolderCTID=0x0120005C60D5FB65C2C84191CB5ACDFD820AA6&View=%7B5AF02A9E%2D451A%2D443D%2DB8CA%2DAF7C7ED6F00C%7D]
```

this is how i pulled in the issue from Jira( my plan is to scan through all issues and update.

```
from jira import JIRA
import re
jira = JIRA(server=('https://mycompanydev.atlassian.net'),basic_auth=('user', 'password'))
issue = jira.issue("S1-3000")
print("Ticket nr: ", issue)
olddescription = issue.fields.description
newdescription = olddescription
```

So i managed to change the first part of the url with this line:

```
newdescription = newdescription.replace("http://portal.mycompany.local/mycompany/someproject/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/someproject/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fmycompany%2Fsomeproject%2F", "https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/CCPortal/")
```

and this line:

```
newdescription = newdescription.replace("http://portal.mycompany.local/mycompany/someproject/SitePages/Home.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fmycompany%2Fsomeproject%2F", "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/CCPortal/")
```

this code completes successfully and changes the URL as intended.

Now i need to remove the end of the url from the string "View=" and the string "FolderCTID="
my line of code to do this:

```
newdescription = newdescription.replace(newdescription[newdescription.find("View=")-1:newdescription.find("]")],"")
```

and:

```
newdescription = newdescription.replace(newdescription[newdescription.find("FolderCTID="):newdescription.find("]")], "")
```

for some reason it only does the first 2 URLs:
result looks like this:

```
Good day 

we need a new validation on the External Reference when doing work pads or amending manually when we do refund, it seems that the user that updates this is using Tab or Enter and therefore the payment files fails ,

we need users to be validated while updating refund reference same way as we limited claims payments for updating invoice numbers

thank you 
regards 

*BRS & FRS:*
[BRS_FRS_PS_ACC_Payments_v20.0|https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mycompany/someproject%2F06%20Solution%20Documentation%2F03%20Accounting%2C%20Etc%2F07%20TIA%2FBRS%20%26%20FRS]
[BRS_FRS_PS_ACC_Workpads_Manual_Write_Off_and_Incomming_Paument_v5.0|https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mycompany/someproject%2F06%20Solution%20Documentation%2F03%20Accounting%2C%20Etc%2F07%20TIA%2FBRS%20%26%20FRS]

*Sign Offs:*
[BRS_FRS_PS_ACC_Payments_v20.0|https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mycompany/someproject%2F06%20Solution%20Documentation%2F03%20Accounting%2C%20Etc%2F07%20TIA%2FBRS%20%26%20FRS%2FSign%2Doffs%2FPayments%2FV20%2E0&FolderCTID=0x0120005C60D5FB65C2C84191CB5ACDFD820AA6]
[BRS_FRS_PS_ACC_Workpads_Manual_Write_Off_and_Incomming_Paument_v5.0|https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mycompany/someproject%2F06%20Solution%20Documentation%2F03%20Accounting%2C%20Etc%2F07%20TIA%2FBRS%20%26%20FRS%2FSign%2Doffs%2FWorkpads%20%26%20incoming%20payments%2FV5%2E0&FolderCTID=0x0120005C60D5FB65C2C84191CB5ACDFD820AA6]

*Technical Documentation:*
N/A

*Unit Testing:*
[TU_MV-1821|https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mycompany/someproject%2F06%20Solution%20Documentation%2F03%20Accounting%2C%20Etc%2F07%20TIA%2FUnit%20Testing&FolderCTID=0x0120005C60D5FB65C2C84191CB5ACDFD820AA6&View=%7B5AF02A9E%2D451A%2D443D%2DB8CA%2DAF7C7ED6F00C%7D]
```

as you can see the code removed the first 2 "View=" strings with the trailing string to the end.

I cant figure out where I went wrong I also tried putting this in a while loop and just repeating the code 5 times for a test.

Comment: It works for me on the example strings you gave. You didn't show the code that creates `newdescription` but perhaps it is missing the trailing `]`?

Comment: thanks For reply, i added the code I used to get the ticket into the variable

Comment: I see, so `newdescription` contains actually all the text, including various different links? Note that `str.find` will only find the first occurrence, so if you have multiple links ending with `]` then it will be only effective for the first. Instead you can use `newdescription.find(']', offset)` where `offset = newdescription.find("View=")`. This will search for `[` starting from `offset` and hence find the *next* occurrence `]`, not the overall first one.

Comment: awesome, the offset is what I needed to figure this out, thanks I put tohether a quick for loop and it works, please will you post this as a answer so that I can mark it as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.find` returns the lowest index where the substring is found. So if `newdescription` has more than one `"]"`, presumably because it contains more than one link, that means the returned index will only be correct for the first link.

`str.find` also accepts an optional start/end index to limit the search, so you can use the index of `"View="` as an offset for the search for `"]"`:

```
offset = newdescription.find("View=")
replace_me = newdescription[offset:newdescription.find("]", offset)]
newdescription = newdescription.replace(replace_me, "")
```